# Exception throw after refresh the itemsource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, dispatcher

*After refreshing its data source then clicking a cell on the grid, it just throws an exception. It seems to be a threading issue.*

Anyone know the root cause for this issue or in which scenario it will occur?

Here's the error message and stacktrace. Exception Message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

`Stack Trace`

> [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>       at Syncfusion.Windows.Controls.Cells.VirtualizingCellsControl.InvalidateCell(CellSpanInfoBase span, Boolean dirtycelluielemet)
>       at Syncfusion.Windows.Controls.Grid.GridControlBase.InvalidateCell(CellSpanInfoBase span)
>       at Syncfusion.Windows.Controls.Grid.GridModel.InvalidateCell(CellSpanInfoBase span)
>       at Syncfusion.Windows.Controls.Grid.GridDataTableModel.b__4()
>       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: As far as I can tell this is coming from inside the library that handles control invalidation. This could possibly be the grid is losing it's data somehow, so when it constructs the args for your event, it cannot find the data. Debug through after the refresh and try to see if the data is off somehow. How are you refreshing the grid data?

P.S. Any interaction with the XAML components happens on the dispatcher thread. If you crossed the thread ie. set variables somewhere, then it will throw a specialized exception telling you that a thread is accessing something that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: Could I see some code that you are using to refresh the grid?